Identify movie with pickup truck racing a red Ferrari
So around 1995 I saw a movie where this guy goes into a bar and ends up being forced (I think) to race some guy in a Ferrari.
A little more detail I remember about the scene: 

The bar looks like the one from the Dukes of Hazzard  
It's an old pickup truck ... maybe 50's or 60's.  Looks all beaten up.  
Some rich guy walks in and hears about how the pickup truck is super fast.  
The rich guy bets the owner of the pickup truck that he can't beat his car in a race.  
Everyone goes outside and they see the rich guy is driving a red Ferrari.  
The whole scene was filmed at night ...   

Anyone know what movie that is from?

This might be Thunder Run. 

A Korean War veteran/aging trucker spends his retirement mining an old cobalt mine with the assistance of his devoted grandson. A good friend lures the trucker out of retirement by offering him a quarter of a million dollars to drive some plutonium from Nevada to a high-security operation in Arizona. He begins his trek in a high-tech rig unaware that terrorists are waiting to ambush him and his deadly cargo.

Early in the film, the protagonist's grandson races his pickup truck against a sports car and wins. Here's the full movie on YouTube. The race starts at around 19:30




Thank you but that wasn't the movie I was thinking about.  Appreciate the help though ...
